# How to manage data in JS object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

What is the best way to manage collections with unique names? I've picked object to go with, and here is an example object to describe my issue:

```
var examplerooms = {
        lobby: {
            users: {
                id4346334: {
                    n: "hello",
                    ip: "192.168.0.1"
                },
                id12345: {
                    n: "another",
                    ip: "192.168.0.1"
                },
                id78978: {
                    n: "user",
                    ip: "192.168.0.1"
                }
            }
        },
        another: {
            users: {
                id23356: {
                    n: "hello",
                    ip: "192.168.0.1"
                },
                id3400: {
                    n: "sad",
                    ip: "192.168.0.1"
                },
                id777777: {
                    n: "one",
                    ip: "192.168.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

adding and deleting specific elements are very easy this way. However, I need to list certain stuff, or compare certain stuff sometimes. I can't find smooth solutions for queries such as:
"All users with name "hello", or is "hello" present as a username (n)?"

I can do primitive stuff with Object.keys, but it's not flexible.

I've checked javascript collections, and I've also read about objects. However everything is still very blurry in my head.

Any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: How would you do it in any other language?

Comment: I don't know any other language sadly. @limelights

Comment: It "feels" to me like `users` should be an array.

Comment: @torazaburo I did it like that to be able to reach specific (and unique) users easily

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model

Answer (score -1):

Convert data to array, so you'll see:

```
var examplerooms = {
    lobby: {
        users: [
            {
                id: 4346334,
                n: "hello",
                ip: "192.168.0.1"
            },
            {
                id: 12345,
                n: "another",
                ip: "192.168.0.1"
            },
            {
                id: 78978.
                n: "user",
                ip: "192.168.0.1"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

so you can do all you want with them:

```
var users = examplerooms.lobby.users;
for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
    if(users[i].n.indexOf('hello') !== -1){
        console.log(users[i]);
    }
}
```